# I still have room for improvement "in that area" - is this necessary?

Tags: meaning, redundancy

**Example 1**

> I have been singing professionally for two years. However, I still have room for improvement.

**Example 2**

> I have been singing professionally for two years. However, I still have room for improvement **in that area**.

Is Example 1 sufficient?

Or we have to use Example 2?

Comment: Your 1st sentence is up to the mark.

Comment: In ***what*** area? Singing in general, or *professional* singing? Better not to include those final three words unless you know exactly why you thought you needed them. (It's hardly likely whoever you're talking to would think you meant you still have room for improvement in, say, learning English! :)

Answer (score 2):

Both versions are correct. In Example 1, it's quite obvious that the "room for improvement" in question must be related to the "singing professionally" in the preceding sentence.